# Getting live data with import.io in Excel

Tags: excel, import.io

Import.io seems to be a great tool when it comes to data. I have created an API which works great. My question is not how can I implement it into an Excel sheet so that I could press a button to start crawling and showing the crawled data in the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy to work with GoogleSheets, there is an option to Export the API to GoogleSheets from the import.io "My Data" page, which calls via the API when you open the sheet - Your data will refresh each time you open the file.